# Ruby: How to dynamically create a subclass of an existing class?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm writing Ruby code that creates new classes using Object.const_set, which works great for creating new classes and instantiating instances of them. But I'd like these new classes to inherit from a class I've hardcoded already. I can't find methods to do this. Here's my code:

```
def create_model_class(klass_name, klass_vars)
    klass = Object.const_set(klass_name, Class.new)
    klass.class_eval do
        define_method(:initialize)
            klass_vars.each_with_index do |name, i|
                instance_variable_set("@"+name[i], name[i])
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I think the `do` after `define_method` has gone awol.  It appears that `klass_vars` is a two-dimensional array.  Is that intended?  If klass_vars is an just array of strings, I think you need to change `each_with_index` to `each` and drop the reference to `i`.  RE @Sergios suggestion, I believe you would add `parent_class` to the arguments and add `(parent_class)` to `Class.new` or add `parent_class_name` to the arguments and `(parent_class_name.to_sym)` to `Class.new`.

Comment: Hey Cary, klass_vars is a hash. I'm only partway through implementing it so I may be muddying the pool by leaving it in this example code. Thanks for the sharp eye.

Comment: A hash, of course.  ...but maybe return the errant `do`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Class.new` accepts a parameter, which will be the superclass.

Documentation: [Class.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-c-new).

Comment: I'd forgotten about that, Sergio.  Thanks for the twig.  Much better than `eval "class B < A; end"`

Comment: 1. I'm not sure where I'd call Class.new with a parameter – my guess is after I define the constant for the class name?  2. I looked at this [lecture](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/metaprogramming-ruby) and apparently for some things in metaprogramming eval is the only way, although I understand how it can create security issues.